# VBA Macro "find" function not actually finding a value in the column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro that will look for a given value in a row, and will find and select that value once it's found (I'll do more with it later, just working on finding/selecting right now).

The problem is that it does not find the value that it should.  The value that I'm looking for, "7/26/2014", is located in cell LS3 in my Excel spreadsheet.  The code to find it is below:

```
With Sheets("Rota").Range("LS3")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:="7/26/2014", _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
End With
```

However, no matter what I'm getting the "Nothing Found" message.  Can somebody please assist?

Comment: Try `What:=#7/26/2014#` instead of `What:="7/26/2014"`, because the cell might be interpreted as a `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code to search all the cells in a specific row.

```
Sub FindIt()
    Dim colNo As Long:      colNo = 2             ' hardcoded to look in col 2
    Dim ws    As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet  ' on the active sheet
    Dim rgCol As Range
    Set rgCol = ws.Columns(colNo)                          ' full col range (huge)
    Set rgCol = Application.Intersect(ws.UsedRange, rgCol) ' shrink to nec size
    Dim rgZeroCells As Range ' range to hold all the "0" cells (union of disjoint cells)
    Dim rgCell      As Range ' single cell to iterate

    For Each rgCell In rgCol.Cells
        If Not IsError(rgCell) Then
            If rgCell.Value <> "7/26/2014" Then                  'your search parameter
                If rgZeroCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set rgZeroCells = rgCell                     ' found 1st one, assign
                Else
                    Set rgZeroCells = Union(rgZeroCells, rgCell) ' found another, append
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next rgCell

    If Not rgZeroCells Is Nothing Then
        ' do something with rgZeriCells that you found earlier... 
        ' rgZeroCells.EntireRow.Delete    ' i.e. deletes all the target rows at once
    End If  

End Sub
```

Comment: By the way, I tried your code on an empty workbook/sheet and just copy+pasted the search term/date you have - and it found it... Double check that the format you have in that cell is the right format. It might be in a different format but display it in another...

Comment: Thanks Kings.  The core problem then seems to be that it's not finding the text in LS3 because it's vertically aligned.  Is there an option to throw into Find that will search Vertically Aligned text?

Comment: The alignment should not be an issue at all. It works for me with all alignments

Comment: Kings - I'm a bit confused looking at your code, now that I'm testing it out.  Is the code looking through all of Column #2, or all of Row #2?  The variable names/comments seem to indicate column, but the functionality is for Row.  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: It is looking in a column not rows. and as it is right now, it is looking in column 2 = B Column

Comment: Ok, got it.  I'll tweak it a bit to look in row 3 instead of column 3. But other than that, it looks like it will do the trick. Thanks again

Comment: Try using Rows(3) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836836(v=office.15).aspx